# How to make the Chromebook's Linux VM terminal run automatically when booting/booting up?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, chromebook, google-chrome-os

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPDvM.jpg)

How to make the Chromebook's Linux VM terminal run automatically when booting/booting up?.

I hope that maybe someone has tried it, maybe there is someone who has experience in Linux and Chromebook.

All suggestions and answers are greatly appreciated.